# Removing variables from strings with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I have a string that contains this:

```
value="'+c+'"
```

and want to use regular expressions to get rid of the single quotes, plus signs, and anything inbetween them:

```
value=""
```

here's what I'm trying:

```
responseFromServer = Regex.Replace(responseFromServer, @"=""'\+.+?\+'""", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

solution:

```
responseFromServer = Regex.Replace(responseFromServer, "'[+].*[+]'", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: And the problem with your solution is that it removes everything after `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the expression that matches all between the `'+` and `+'` in the given example:

```
'[+].*[+]'
```

If you also want to match with look behind and look ahead, you can try:

```
(?<==")'[+].*[+]'(?=")
```

which checks for `="` before the match and `"` after the match.

You can also extend this to look for the value name before the `=`, which I expect changes. Depends on what exactly those value names can contain.

Comment: Tried the first solution, worked great, thanks
`code`responseFromServer = Regex.Replace(responseFromServer, "'[+].*[+]'", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);

Answer (score 0):

```
string afterReplace = Regex.Replace(responseFromServer, @"'\+[^+]*\+'", "", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
Regex.Replace(responseFromServer, @"(')(\\+)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))(\\+)(')", "", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```